# deb/rules: No such file or directory

Tags: linux-kernel, debian, fakeroot

I was trying to build vmlinux image for my 2.6.32 kernel in ubuntu-10.04 referencing  [this tutorial](http://www.crashcourse.ca/introduction-linux-kernel-programming/intermission-building-vmlinux-file-under-ubuntu-free-lesson). These are the steps I followed.
1. Installed build tools with
`sudo apt-get build-dep linux-image-$(uname -r)`
 2. Downloaded the source using
`apt-get source linux-image-$(uname -r)`
 3. cd'ed  to the extracted source directory and run
`fakeroot debian/rules clean`
but it gives me the error

```
fakeroot deb/rules clean    
/usr/bin/fakeroot: line 176: deb/rules: No such file or directory
```

My new uncompressed kernel source directory doesn't contains any directory named deb or deb/rules. So what they actually they mean by `fakeroot debian/rules clean` ?   How can I locate the file `debian/rules`?

Found [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/143670/error-installing-libatlas) without any solved answer.  Please help